# One avatar's slot is missing from Winter Bash leaderboard

Tags: bug, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021, winterbash-leaderboard

On the [Winterbash 2021 Leaderboard](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) page, in the Mathematics.SE leaderboard display, one slot for the fifth avatar is missing.

[image]

---

Update:
It is still happening on Physical Fitness.SE's display.

[image]

Comment: @Suraj There are many users tied for #5 and it selects one somewhat randomly in that case. The problem is that #4 is missing from the leaderboard, and there is only one person listed at #3. I'd venture a guess that it's some hidden community issue. Someone holds #4 but can't be displayed.

Comment: @animuson oh true. The leaderboard has skipped #4 completely.

Comment: Maybe the #4 disabled hats?

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It seems to be fixed. Don't know why. Maybe the previous #4 disabled hats.

This is how it looks like now:

[image]

Comment: Does that mean I won't get the unicorn hat? But I will get monologue, dialogue but trialogue depends on you.(add bug fixed tag in the answer)

Comment: @Wolgwang Don't know, haha!

Comment: Uhm. [It](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5psWn.jpg) is still displaying only 4 avatar.

Comment: @Wolgwang What... Again

Comment: Also happening in physics fitness. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHOiP.jpg